# Shadow effect is not displaying properly for UIView

Tags: ios, swift

I have a login screen as below. Around each text field I have added a view and for that view I want to display a drop shadow. I kind of achieved what I was trying but this thing is not working for iPhone Plus (6+,8+) devices.

You can see the difference below.

iPhone 8+:-

[image]

iPhone 8:-

[image]

Here is my code

```
extension UIView {
    func addShadow() {        
        layer.cornerRadius = 8
        layer.masksToBounds = true

        layer.shadowColor = UIColor.lightGray.cgColor
        layer.shadowOffset = CGSize(width: 0, height: 1.0)
        layer.shadowRadius = 2.0
        layer.shadowOpacity = 0.5
        layer.masksToBounds = false

        layer.shadowPath = UIBezierPath(roundedRect: self.bounds,cornerRadius:8).cgPath
    }
}
```

How I can fix this properly?

Comment: your code is right.go to storyboard ShowTheAttributeInspcter>simulatedmetrics>set size iphone 8+ than check you have exact problem what you faces

Comment: You are checking this in device or simulator? If in simulator might be its stretch and not fully visible. Try to expand the simulator by dragging from its corner and then see if it is actually an issue.

Comment: Attached images are of simulator but i have also tried on actual device too.

Comment: You have received two answers both are correct logically... Have a try!

Comment: **Just for info:** `viewDidLayoutSubviews()` calls multiple times so never do any adding work here (`layer` or `view`) for layer case it will add multiple layers and shadow will look darker.

Comment: Sure. Thankyou :)

Comment: @TheTiger: The code adds no layer. It configures just one. Thus, you may call this method from `viewDidLayoutSubviews() `.

Comment: @clemens I'm saying just for information not specifying these answers. I know these both are correct answers and not adding any layer again.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Since the views may be resized you should update your `shadowPath` after resizing because it has a fixed size. Unfortunately this can't be done in an extension, because you need to overwrite `layoutSubview()`. But you may call `addShadow()` from `viewDidLayoutSubviews()` from your view controller *again* for each text field.

You may also modify your extension to only update the path:

```
extension UIView {
    func addShadow() {        
        layer.cornerRadius = 8

        layer.shadowColor = UIColor.lightGray.cgColor
        layer.shadowOffset = CGSize(width: 0, height: 1.0)
        layer.shadowRadius = 2.0
        layer.shadowOpacity = 0.5
        layer.masksToBounds = false

        updateShadow()
    }
    func updateShadow() {
        layer.shadowPath = UIBezierPath(roundedRect: self.bounds,cornerRadius:8).cgPath
    }  
}
```

With this you should call `updateShadow()` from `viewDidLayoutSubviews()` for each view with a shadow.

If you use a custom subclass for your text fields you may put the `updateShadow()` call into `layoutSubviews()`. So you need not to call it from the view controller.

Answer (score 2):

> You are building the view on iPhone 8 on storyboard. So when you run it on iPhone 8+/ 6+, view gets resized but shadow does not get updated.

[image]

**Put `layoutIfNeeded()` before adding `shadowPath` to `layer`:**

Updated code will look like:

```
func addShadow() {
    layer.cornerRadius = 8
    layer.masksToBounds = true

    layer.shadowColor = UIColor.lightGray.cgColor
    layer.shadowOffset = CGSize(width: 0, height: 1.0)
    layer.shadowRadius = 2.0
    layer.shadowOpacity = 0.5
    layer.masksToBounds = false

    layoutIfNeeded()
    layer.shadowPath = UIBezierPath(roundedRect: self.bounds,cornerRadius: 8).cgPath
}
```

Comment: This will not work after a device rotation or other resizes of the view.

Comment: @clemens Correct but will work for this problem. So we can not say it wrong!

Comment: @aqsaarshad, If you are using portrait mode only, then it will work fine.

Comment: Landscape is also supported. +1 for correct answer.

Comment: @TheTiger: I never said it's wrong. It doesn't work for all cases. It will not resize the shadows using Split Screen on an iPad.

Answer (score 2):

I'm sharing my approach that worked for me. I have used **@clemens** extension which is:

```
extension UIView {
    func addShadow() {        
        layer.cornerRadius = 8
        layer.shadowColor = UIColor.lightGray.cgColor
        layer.shadowOffset = CGSize(width: 0, height: 1.0)
        layer.shadowRadius = 2.0
        layer.shadowOpacity = 0.5
        layer.masksToBounds = false

        updateShadow()
    }

    func updateShadow() {
        layer.shadowPath = UIBezierPath(roundedRect: self.bounds, cornerRadius: 8).cgPath
    }  
}
```

However, it didn't work until this:

```
override func viewDidLayoutSubviews() {
    super.viewDidLayoutSubviews()
    // Async is the key in this situation :)
    DispatchQueue.main.async { [weak self] in
        self?.someButton.addShadowNice()
        self?.someButton.updateShadow()
    }
}
```

Cheers.