# How to remove extra black shadow in some iPhones while giving shadow for UIView in swift?

Tags: swift, iphone, uiview, shadow

I have given shadow for three views. And the shadow coming perfectly in iPhone 8 plus, iPhone 11, iPhone 11 pro max. like below

[image: correct shadow]

I am getting dark black shade in right sides in iPhone 8, iPhone 7 plus, iPhone 7 why? like below

[image: black colour]

How to remove the black colour from right side in iPhone8.

Below code for UIView shadow :

```swift
firstContainerView.clipsToBounds = false
firstContainerView.layer.shadowColor = UIColor.black.cgColor
firstContainerView.layer.shadowOpacity = 1
firstContainerView.layer.shadowOffset = CGSize(width: 0.2, height: 0.2)
firstContainerView.layer.shadowRadius = 1
firstContainerView.layer.shadowPath = UIBezierPath(roundedRect: 
firstContainerView.bounds, cornerRadius: cornerRadius).cgPath
```

Why extra black shadow coming in some devices.
Please help me to remove the extra black colour from shadow in iPhone 8, iPhone 7 plus.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

according to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49665421/5928311) you can create extension with your parameters:

```
extension UIView {
    func addShadow() {
        layer.shadowColor = UIColor.black.cgColor
        layer.shadowOffset = CGSize(width: 0.2, height: 0.2)
        layer.shadowRadius = 1
        layer.shadowOpacity = 1
        layer.masksToBounds = false

        updateShadow()
    }
    func updateShadow() {
        layer.shadowPath = UIBezierPath(roundedRect: self.bounds,cornerRadius: 5).cgPath
    }
}
```

and call it in `viewDidLayoutSubviews()` like here

```
override func viewDidLayoutSubviews() {
    super.viewDidLayoutSubviews()

    viewTest.addShadow()
}
```

I hope this helps you for iPhone 7 and etc.

Comment: yes its perfectly working, may i know where i did mistake in my above post.. why i use to get extra black colour?? why i am not getting with your answer?

Comment: @iPhoneDev I'd say this is related to the life cycle of the view controller. You can check `viewTest.bounds` in `viewDidLoad()` and `viewDidLayoutSubviews` the sizes will most likely differ for iPhone 7/8, but the same for iPhone 8 Plus (why - honestly, I don't know), because `viewDidLayoutSubviews` сalled to notify the view controller that its view has just laid out its subviews. Therefore it is necessary to update our `shadowPath` based on the current (latest) information about the size of our `view` on the view controller.